# Просмотр файловой системы сервера через браузер

Tags: ssh, centos, ftp, vps

Есть VPS на CentOS
ЧТобы обменивакться файлами приходится по ftp или ssh подключаться к серваку. Часто наталкиваюсь на то что файловая система других серверов отображается как сайт в браузере. 
Скажите как такого добиться? 
Спасибо!

Comment: Как вариант поставить С-панель на сервер, вот например бесплатная - https://vestacp.com/

Comment: А это разве не со стороны хостинг-провайдера ставится? 
Есть ли альтернативы?

Comment: Этот вариант можно поставить самостоятельно, не задавался вопросом таких штук и альтернатив

Comment: Это ж вы Web-Shell хотите...

Comment: Нужен веб-сервер и настройка показывать каталоги. Например, http://nginx.org/ru/docs/http/ngx_http_index_module.html